# Custom form field in subform. How to access parent form fields?

Tags: custom-field, joomla-3.9, subform

I have created a custom file list form field and the field is used in a repeatable subform.

The purpose of this custom form field is to display a list of files in folder based on 'name' field in main form.

The problem I've encountered is: How to get the 'name' field from the custom form field to redirect to specific folder?

The form object (`$this->form`) is the subform object.

How to access the main/parent form fields to get the required 'name' field value?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, its simply not possible - i had to use javascript for a similar scenario (the other way around) and loaded the files by AJAX inside a modal.

the "logic" was:
Get the targetfield's id that holds the filename after a subform got added, custom modal that holds target field id and its value as data attr. after selecting a file js stores the filepath in the field... It started to get complicated when added subform multiple mode.

You can download agileDownloads to have a look for the Custom form field I've created there:
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/agile-downloads-lite/

[image]